# How to design a special MapReduce inverted index?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

In this case I have lots of logs.
Each log contains time, ip, url, content, etc.

Question 1:
What I want to do is to determine that give you a **certain word** like 'google', tell me which log's content **contains this word**.

Question 2:
I can't make sure which word I prefer, so give me the whole inverted index answer.

So, my question is:
For question 1, how to design the mapper & reducer?

- I can use mapper to split the content of log, and the output of mapper is lots of k-v pairs of `<'word', log_id>`. The reducer should walk through all of these answers, and if it meets a pair like `<'google', log_id>`, output it.
- And I can also use mapper to work through the whole content, if it meets the word 'google', it gives an output of `<'google', log_id>`, if it meets other words, just skip. If the mapper doesn't meet the specific word, it output nothing.In this case, the reducer just output, it doesn't need to work through.

So could you tell me which one is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two do different things.  Your second implementation works for question 1, when you have an exact word you're looking for.  Your first implementation works for question 2, when you don't know the word you're looking for.  These are different problems with different solutions.

If you're *just* looking to solve question 1, then your second algorithm will work fine and work faster.